# How to hard code days part in dates in crystal reports

Tags: date, crystal-reports

I am new to crystal reports. I have two date fields on my report: `Benefit Start` **&** `Benefit End Dates`.

I have to compare the age of the employees.

```
1) If age>65 years, Benefit Start date should be '20160101'.
2) If age<65 years, Benefit Start date should be first day of the month effective. 
eg: if the date is '09/21/2015', the output should be'09/01/2015'.
```

Similarly for benefit End Date,

```
If age<65 years, Benefit End date should be last day of the month effective.
eg:  if the date is '09/02/2015', the output should be'09/30/2015'.
```

How to hard code the days in dates so that I get the first day & last day of the months for the two fields?

Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to get first day of the month use

```
DateSerial ((Year (CurrentDate)),(Month (CurrentDate)) ,Day (Minimum (LastFullMonth)))
```

to get last day use

```
Dateserial(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)+1,1-1)
```

please replace CurrentDate with your Date formula.

Comment: Thank you for your post.